# C++. Weighted std::shuffle

Tags: c++, c++11, random, shuffle, weighted

Is there a way to do nice and elegant weighted shuffling using standard library? 
There is `std::discrete_distribution`. 
What I want is something like this:

```
std::vector<T> data { N elements };
std::vector<int> weights { N weights };
std::shuffle(std::begin(data), std::end(data), something based on discrete distribution);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate (maybe with an example) on what do you mean by "weighted shuffling"?

Comment: @Bob__ I would venture something like this: http://nicky.vanforeest.com/probability/weightedRandomShuffling/weighted.html

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Ah. So something like this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/SuTYLHHG8brNNieq

Comment: @Bob__ Yep, looks good... You ought to post it as an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If OP intent is to shuffle a list **r** of items

> such that, given a list of weights **w**, the element **a[i]** with weight **w[i]** should be the first element of the random shuffle **r** with probability **w[i]/sum(w)**.

As stated in the [page](http://nicky.vanforeest.com/probability/weightedRandomShuffling/weighted.html) linked by [Severin Pappadeux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4044696/severin-pappadeux):

> Weighted random shuffling is the same as weighted random sampling from a list a without replacement. That is, choose with probability w[i]/sum(w) element a[i] from a. Store this element in a list r. Then, remove element a[i] from a and w[i] from w, and select a new element of the modified list a, and so on until a is empty.

I'am not aware of such an algorithm in the Standard Library, but a simple implementation could be:

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <class D, class W, class URBG>
void weighted_shuffle
    ( D first, D last
    , W first_weight, W last_weight
    , URBG&& g )
{
    while (first != last and first_weight != last_weight)
    {
        std::discrete_distribution dd(first_weight, last_weight);
        auto i = dd(g);
        if ( i )
        {
            std::iter_swap(first, std::next(first, i));
            std::iter_swap(first_weight, std::next(first_weight, i));
        }
        ++first;
        ++first_weight;
    }
}
```

Live example [HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mQuweFbRgjaverpn).

Comment: nice. but why the `if ( i )`?

Comment: @JHBonarius well, premature optimization, I think. It's just to save the unnecessary *cost* of swapping and advancing the iterators. The random part should be the more time consuming, anyways.

Comment: ah, I get it now. It prevents swapping an element with itself.

Comment: I needed to do this: std::discrete_distribution<int> dd(first_weight, last_weight)

Comment: @supo Yes, that kind of type deduction is a C++17 feature. If you can only target C++11, you can do something like this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Bf3MIVP1avVIYjAG

Comment: @Bob__ Frankly, the branching could even be slower than the occasional extra swap.

Comment: @SolomonUcko Well, [yes](http://quick-bench.com/9A3LIIROzxSbRPdMXuUQPjJq1I8), it could be or [not](http://quick-bench.com/na2bMzmzW83v-HKIu4uJNzu44lc). When I wrote this, I was thinking about containers where `std::next(first, i)` would be O(n) (note that `std::shuffle` requires random iterators), so that it could have made sense to optimize that corner case. Of course in those cases it would be better to copy the data into a vector and transform that instead. In general, I agree, it's a *premature* optimization and I'll probably end up removing it.

Comment: I suspect this answer runs in time O(n^2) because the discrete_distribution constructor is O(n).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Weighted Random Sampling (2005; Efraimidis, Spirakis)](http://utopia.duth.gr/%7Epefraimi/research/data/2007EncOfAlg.pdf).  If you create a list of values `-pow(rand(0,1), weights[i])` and sort this, you will get what you want.

Equivalently (and slightly faster), this list can be created using an exponential distribution.

```
std::vector<size_t> weighted_shuffle(std::vector<double> const &weights, std::mt19937 &rng)
{
    //auto uniform_dist = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>();
    auto exp_dist = std::exponential_distribution<double>();

    std::vector<std::pair<double, size_t>> index_pairs;
    index_pairs.reserve(weights.size());
    for (size_t i=0; i<weights.size(); ++i) {
        double const p = weights[i];
        // from Efraimidis, Spirakis
        //index_pairs.emplace_back(-std::pow(uniform_dist(rng), 1.0/p), i);
        // equivalent and a bit faster
        //index_pairs.emplace_back(-std::log(uniform_dist(rng))/p, i);
        // equivalent and fastest
        index_pairs.emplace_back(exp_dist(rng)/p, i);
    }
    std::sort(index_pairs.begin(), index_pairs.end());

    std::vector<size_t> indices;
    indices.reserve(weights.size());
    for (auto const &[w, i] : index_pairs)
        indices.emplace_back(i);
    return indices;
}
```