# Choose a random sample from a list with bias in Python

Tags: python, numpy, random, genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman

To give a little background, I am coding a genetic algorithm to solve the [Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). In my population, I have an ordered list of paths from shortest to longest (fittest to least fit), and their respective distances, like this:

```
population = [
[[a, b, c, d], [10.12]],
[[b, c, a, d], [11.33]],
[[d, a, c, b], [11.5]],
[[b, a, d, c], [12.07]]
...]
```

After the population is ordered by their fitness, I need to kill half of them randomly, but in such a fashion that the fitter the member, the better their chance of surviving.

1. I've tried using [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) and passing a list with chances of probability *(bias)* into the `weights` parameter, and my desired size of half the original population as `k` like this:

   ```
   # returns something like [0.99, 0.75, 0.65, 0.22...]
   bias_weights = [x / len(population) for x in range(len(population))]

   random.choices(population, weights=bias_weights, k=len(population) / 2)
   ```

   The problem with the code above is that it **produces duplicates** in my list, and it's very messy to get rid of them and keep the population size at 50%.
2. I've also tried using the [`np.random.choices()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice) from the `numpy` library, but it requires the list that I am passing **to be 1D**, and the list of weights and biases to **add up to 1**.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would still use `np.random.choice()`. Solve the first problem by asking `np.random.choice()` to choose the *index* of the path rather than the path itself. Solve the second problem by scaling the weights so they sum to 1.

```
import numpy as np

a, b, c, d = 1, 2, 3, 4

population = [
[[a, b, c, d], [10.12]],
[[b, c, a, d], [11.33]],
[[d, a, c, b], [11.5]],
[[b, a, d, c], [12.07]]
]

# Build probability array
bias_weights = [x / len(population) for x in range(len(population))]
prob = np.array(bias_weights) / np.sum(bias_weights)

# Get random integers between 0 and len(prob)-1, drawn according to prob
sample_size = 2
choice_indices = np.random.choice(len(prob), size=sample_size, replace=False, p=prob)

# Get corresponding paths
paths = [population[i][0] for i in choice_indices]
```

Comment: How would I be able to scale this for 50% of the original data? The problem with the code above is that the same element could be chosen twice, which I do not want. Also, if I were to get rid of them in some kind of loop, I would also have to change the size of the `prob` list according to which element has been taken out. very messy.

Comment: @KomronAripov You can still use [`choice()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). I updated my code above to allow an arbitrary sample size.

Comment: this produces the following error: `ValueError: Fewer non-zero entries in p than size`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Actually, I would recommend to just use the following:

```
while <variable> not in <list>:
    <list>.append(<variable>)
```

Comment: Could you possibly provide code along with your answer? I'm struggling on the technical side of things with Python.

Comment: This does not seem like a good solution as the number of elements `[a, b, c and d]` can change any time (that is the nature of the program) and I would not be able to add `for` clauses dynamically.

Comment: It's actually fairly easy to handle a dynamic list size with "for item in all_stuff:" with "battle_royale.append(item)", but the number of times each item should be appended to the battle_royale list requires a more intricate approach.  It could be accomplished with classes, for example.  

Anyway, I just realized my suggestion is way overly complicated.  What you have is good, just use "while ___ not in ___:"

Answer (score 1):

Choose one element at a time, put it into a set to guarantee it's unique, and continue until you have enough elements:

```
bias_weights = [x / len(population) for x in range(len(population))]

chosen = set()

while size(chosen) < len(population) // 2:
    chosen.add(random.choices(population, weights=bias_weights, k=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

For no duplicates you have to use random shuffle. Algorithm is called weighted random shuffle, and is solved in

http://nicky.vanforeest.com/probability/weightedRandomShuffling/weighted.html

C++ version is right here

[C++. Weighted std::shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221136/c-weighted-stdshuffle)

UPDATE: Fast weighted random shuffle copied from first link verbatim

```
from random import random
from bisect import bisect_right
import numpy as np

def weighted_shuffle(a,w):
    r = np.empty_like(a)
    cumWeights = np.cumsum(w)
    for i in range(len(a)):
         rnd = random() * cumWeights[-1]
         j = bisect_right(cumWeights,rnd)
         #j = np.searchsorted(cumWeights, rnd, side='right')
         r[i]=a[j]
         cumWeights[j:] -= w[j]
    return r

a = np.arange(1,1000)
w = np.arange(1,1000)
r = weighted_shuffle(a,w)
print(r[:2])
```

Comment: Is there a python version of what you've described?

Comment: @KomronAripov did you check first link? It is Python as far as I can see