# Effectively choose subset where each item has probability to be picked

Tags: python, numpy, random, subset

Challenge here)

**THE STORY**

I have a big sequence of objects:

```
OBJS = [o_1, o_2, ..., o_n]
```

Each object can be recalculated (which is expencive). During recalculation it may add and remove items from the sequence:

```
class Obj:
    def recalculate(self):
        # some expensive calcs here
        ...

        # may add objects
        if create_new_obj:
            OBJS.append(Obj())

        # may remove objects
        if delete_obj:
            del OBJS[idx]
```

And I have a loop recalculating them, which I want to iterate as fast as possible:

```
while True:
    for obj in OBJS:
        obj.recalculate()
```

What I can do is to recalculate not all of them each iteration. I can add a `probability` attribute to an `Obj` class or add probabilities to a sequence like this:

```
OBJS = [
    [o_1, 0.0001],  # recalculate once per 10 000 iterations in average
    [o_2, 1.0],  # recalculate each iteration
    ...,
    [o_n, 0.5]  # recalculate once per 2 iterations in average
]
```

Create a generator which returns subset of objects to be recalculated this iteration:

```
def pick_subset_of_randoms(sequence):
    for obj, probability in sequence:
        if random.random() <= probability:
            yield obj
```

And update the loop like this:

```
while True:
    for obj in pick_subset_of_randoms(OBJS):
        obj.recalculate()
```

**THE PROBLEM**

Is there any chance of optimizing `pick_subset_of_randoms` generator?

The perfect variant would be to avoid `for` loop iterating through all the sequence. Because subset length may be tens or hundreds thousands of times less than the sequence length.

Third-party packages (say `numpy`) are allowed. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ random non-repeated integers with weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599509/c-random-non-repeated-integers-with-weights)

Comment: No, it generates random sample of given size. But I have no exact size of resulting sample, I want it to generate random samples, each of different size, but with a given probability for each item to appear in it.